# In Visual Studio how to remove a class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am learning C#. I had a class under a namespace and it works fine. After adding another class, it says that there are multiple entry points. So I want to delete the other class. Even after deleting the build is failing as it seem to look for the deleted class. What is a clean way to delete a class

Comment: Have you tried a full rebuild?

Comment: What is a full rebuild ? . I just tried selecting the namespace, instead of the class and then  do a rebuild. It still looks for the deleted class. Is that what you mean by full rebuild .. meaning instead of building in class level, build in namespace level ? . If not let me know how to

Comment: Side note: you really should get anything instead of VS 2010... You'll have even harder time with such an ancient version (and correspondingly old C#/.Net versions). There is not much reason not to get the [latest VS 2022](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&channel=Release&version=VS2022&source=VSLandingPage&cid=2030&passive=false)

Comment: Show us the code please. It might be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

> says that there are multiple entry points.

This says that there are multiple Main-methods. so I guess your new class got a copy of `static void Main(string[] args)`. In newer versions of visual studio there can also be "Top Level Statements" that works like a main method, but with less boilerplate.

> Even after deleting the build is failing as it seem to look for the deleted class

This sounds like you deleted a *file* without also deleting it from the project. Check the solution explorer and remove anything with a red cross.

Overall I would recommend reading the [documentations and tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/), and use the latest visual studio and .Net version.